# When Deep Links are available for public?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, deep-linking

I have added deep links to my app, I have tested them from android studio, and its working fine. Now i have few questions.

- If i upload this apk to Alpha, will these links become active and
  available to all users, or they will only become available when i
  promote this apk to production. If so, then how can i test them from
  browser?
- What if someone also creates a same deep link that i am using e.g:
  `myapp://playvideo`. This can be used by many people,  how will 
  playstore open my app and not some other when same deep links are
  being used.

**Manifest**

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="link" android:pathPrefix="/path" android:host="video"/>
```

Comment: Answer to #2: Depending on the schema you used, the OS will prompt the user to select an application which will handle the action; browser or your app (or any other app that can handle it)

Comment: Answer to #1 You can test your application directly  there is no need to post on Alpha or in production , its working in normal way if you are install through Android Studio or copy APK to any Device and install , But Defiantly DeepLinking is working on Alpha , if Schema and host match with URL  open in browser.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by schema? I have edited my question, and post what i am using in Manifest file.